# SocialBootstrapAPI Classic sign-up and Google

Tags: servicestack

WWhen I create a new classic account using the SocialBootstrapAPI Project I have a new UserAuth created in database.

Next, when I logout and try to sign-in with Google OpenID (google account using the same email than the classic sign-in) instead of using the old account it create a new:

[image: Signup classic and Google]

Is it normal ? If not how to merge UserAuth ?
When I debug CreateOrMergeAuthSession in the custom IUserAuthRepository , the userAuth is always a new instance because GetUserAuth with authSession does not have informations (email) to find the old classic UserAuth:

```
var userAuth = GetUserAuth(authSession, tokens) ?? new ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.UserAuth();
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a good solution but it works :

I have edited the following methods :

```
public ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.UserAuth GetUserAuth(IAuthSession authSession, IOAuthTokens tokens)
{

}
```

I have added a control on the tokens email :

```
if (tokens != null && !tokens.Email.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    var userAuth = GetUserAuthByUserName(tokens.Email);
    if (userAuth != null) return userAuth;
}
```

So it get my old userAuth using email on the google mail account.